# JSONSerialization.jsonObject returning nil?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

**Note**: I am on [step 2.3 here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide), I am working to integrate stripe with firebase.

I have the following guard let, which will fail. It fails because of the json const.

```
          guard let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any], let accountURLString = json["url"] as? String, let accountURL = URL(string: accountURLString) else {
                  // handle error
            print(": jsonfdshkfdbsh :")
                return
          }
```

Unfortunately the following declaration within it fails:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
```

**What is wrong with the line? How can I make it work?**

---

**Update**: (What I have tried but *has **not** worked*)

```
            let data = data as Data?
            print(data, " datavar")//has a value (not nil)
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
            print(json, " jsonvar") //nil
            let accountURLString = json!["url"] as? String
            let accountURL = URL(string: accountURLString!)
```

**Update 2:**

I've been wondering and investigating whether the problem may be that `request` variable path may not be valid(?). However, my testing, with a value I know exists in the database, has not yielded (worked) any results.

```
    if let url = URL(string: backendAPIBaseURL)?.appendingPathComponent("stripe_customers/IYNpofaWUFXfobmFRLMLIEZXxqN2") {// usually the string is: "onboard-user"

       var request = URLRequest(url: url)
      request.httpMethod = "POST"
      
        print(URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request), "<-- ay un problem?")
        print(request, " this was the request value")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            print("does thsi run??? ", data)
            
            let data: Data = data!// as Data?
            print(data, " ttekjfdsjklfhdas")
            //...
```

Comment: Can you post a link or some info about the json data you're to parse? JSONSerialization should work, but it also depends on the structure of your json.

Comment: You should also double-check that your JSON is valid. I typically recommend passing it to https://jsonlint.com. Invalid JSON will give you this error. Also, get replace `try?` with `try` and the system will throw you an error telling you the problem. `try?` explicitly says you want to throw away all the helpful error messages.

Comment: Are you sure that your second code snipper is the reason why it fails? The reason might be any subsequent sentences in the guard statement if you didn't check it individually.

Comment: @Rikh Yes, I checked it individually. I am certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be associated with **Update 2**. The `request` was the problem.

I ended changing the code to the following, which worked:

```
    func createStripeConnectAccount(uid: String, completion: @escaping(String?, String?) -> Void)  { //accountID, Error

    let parameters: [String:Any] = [:]

    let url = "https://us-central1-name-fhdskj.cloudfunctions.net/createConnectAccount"

    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let dict):
                print(dict)
                let successDict: [String: Any?] = dict as! [String: Any?]
                let body = successDict["body"] as! [String: Any?]
                let acctNum = body["success"] as! String
                
                print(acctNum, "<-- link did it twerk?")

                completion(acctNum, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}


func createAccountLink(accountID: String, completion: @escaping(String?, String?) -> Void)  { //url, Error

    let parameters: [String:Any] = ["accountID": accountID]

    let url = "https://us-central1-name-fdsad.cloudfunctions.net/createStripeAccountLink"

    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let dict):
                print(dict)
                let successDict: [String: Any?] = dict as! [String: Any?]
                let body = successDict["body"] as! [String: Any?]
                let link = body["success"] as! String
                
                print(link, "<-- link did it twerk?")

                completion(link, nil)
            
        case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

*You'll have to integrate Alomofire Pod.*